# Can I store a ref in Redux store, or is it considered bad practice?

Tags: reactjs, redux

**The context:**

Short explanation why I'm even asking this. I have a React App with Redux. 
I have a component that shows a List of Chat Rooms. I also have a Appbar from Material UI with a position of sticky. Also the list of chatRooms is sticky so it sticks to the left side, without scrolling with the list of chats in the middle. 
This won't work ofc because the list of chatRooms will hide behind the AppBar or better said, overlap with it. So I need to set the `top` value for chatRooms according to the AppBar's height.

**The question:**

My idea was to add `useDimensions` hook and measure the height of the AppBar. I need to pass a ref to the appbar. And then set the `top` value of chatRooms equal to this height. But I can't pass this directly to the component. So my question is:

**Can I store the ref in redux store, or is it considered bad practice? If so how to solve this problem?**

Comment: Put it in the parent component and pass it down as a prop.  You have a parent that must have both components as children so i would do any measuring in the parent and then pass it down to what components need it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't store a ref in your redux store, there are better ways to fix this problem. I have a layout similar than yours and it works with css only. You should avoid sticky because of this overlap problem and use a css grid instead.

Here is my css, as you can see there are no sticky, but just a full page grid:

```
/* Main grid container (2 columns, 2 rows) */
#root {
  height: 100%;
  display: grid; 
  grid-template-columns: 220px 1fr; 
  grid-template-rows: 56px 1fr;
}
/* Top App bar, height=56px */
header { 
  grid-column: span 2; 
}
/* List of chatRooms, width=220px */
aside { 
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto; 
}
/* List of chats */
main { 
   overflow-y: auto; 
}
```

If you want this grid to fill the whole page, then you need to add:

```
html { height: 100% }
body { height: 100% }
```

Comment: Hi, looks awesome will try. I don't use css in my project, just css in js. But I don't mind changing to it. The #root is the whole page?

Comment: The root comes from your index.html file: `<div id="root"></div>`. This is what React uses to render your App. It was created by create-react-app

Comment: Ah yah I see. I have to restructure some things. It looks weird now, because I also use some layout components from Material UI (Grid for example). And the other selectors work out of the box or do I have to put my for example AppBar into a `<header>` element?

Comment: You can put it in `<header>` or replace header with your own className

Comment: And if you need a status bar at the bottom, just change the grid with `grid-template-rows: 56px 1fr 28px` and create a new div that spans 2 columns (like `header`)

Comment: Yeah I also have a sticky textinput on the bottom of the chatList (main). How to change css so this will always stick to bottom? After that I really have to learn grid :)
Right now with your changes, the chatRooms and chatList is underneath each other. Not side by side.

Comment: This is how it looks currently: https://imgur.com/a/harnVoi with this css: https://pastebin.com/eSsxTXD5 - you can see the colors i used on css on the screenshot

Comment: Did you put your chatList inside `<main>`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212535/discussion-between-hermitcrab-and-geraltdiesocke).

Comment: @HermitCrab Hi, I had same question, not for this kind of problem though. Can you please explain if store ref inside redux state is bad practice, why? And if it is bad practice can you point it out how to pass parent div-> (ref) to child component (Which is quite deep in the tree)